# How to get mysql_errno() for INSERT IGNORE

Tags: mysql, key, duplicates

I have following code:

```
$link=mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(raddacen_staff,$link) or die(mysql_error());
$query=mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO database...............") or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){
 echo 'Data Inserted';
}
else{
echo 'error code '.mysql_errno($link);
}
```

While I am trying to insert a record with duplicate key, this code is showing error code as '0'. I want to show user that if a duplicate record is found by detecting error code. This is because mysql_affected_rows() can't be <0 or 0 for many causes, so I need to point out specific error code for duplicate key only.
Do you have any idea how to point out specific error code for duplicate key using INSERT IGNORE query?

Comment: why cant you do exception handling instead of affected rows

Comment: The point of `insert ignore` is to avoid the error generation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html):

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the
>   INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without
>   IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY
>   value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is
>   aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is
>   issued.

So, if you want errors, you need to remove the keyword that hides errors, i.e. `IGNORE`.

Alternatively, you can read *warnings* by issuing a `SHOW WARNINGS` query.